# Setting Environment Variable in git

Tags: git

I have installed git on windows 7.I want to know how to set it's environmental variable path.I also want to know if i have to remove the string that is already there in field of environmental variable.

Comment: Environment variables are an OS feature and not a git feature.

Answer (score 0):

You have, [in addition of %PATH%](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), [**multiple environment variables** used by git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables).

The most important one is HOME (not set by default), which should be set to `%USERPROFILE%`. For instance, git will look for global config as `%HOME%\.gitconfig`.

Other can be overridden at the command-line.
For instance, `GIT_DIR`, (the location of the `.git` folder) is also set with `--git-dir` option.
That is what allows you to add files from a folder *outside* a git repo:

```
cd /external/folder
git --git-dir=/path/to/my/repo/.git add .
```